# Cypress - unable to store response.body data into a JSON file

Tags: cypress

I've created a POST XMLHttpRequest with FormData successfully. I now need to capture it's response body and get it stored in a JSON file.

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  "Post_Clients",
  (imagePath, imageType, attr1, attr2, attr1Val, done) => {
    cy.fixture(imagePath, "binary").then(imageBin => {
      Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(imageBin, imageType).then(blob => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        const data = new FormData();
        data.set(attr1, attr1Val);
        data.set(attr2, blob);
        xhr.open("POST", "https://api.teamapp.myhelpling.com/admin/clients");
        xhr.responseType = "json"
        xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("access-token", accesstoken);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("client", client);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("expiry", expiry);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("token-type", tokentype);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("uid", uid);
        xhr.onload = function() {
          done(xhr);
        };
        xhr.onerror = function() {
          done(xhr);
        };
        xhr.send(data);
      });
    });
  }
);


it.only("API POSTing TEST", () => {
    cy.Post_Clients(
      "/images/clients/Golden JPEG.jpeg",
      "image/jpeg",
      "client[name]",
      "client[client_logo_attributes][content]",
      "Test Attr 1 Value is Hi!!!",
      resp => {
        cy.writeFile(
          "cypress/fixtures/POST API OUTPUT DATA/Client.json",
          resp.response
        );
        expect(response.status).to.eq(201);
      }
    );
  });
```

Kindly note that `expect(response.status).to.eq(201);` assertion works well.

Following code logs the body properly in the console

```
cy.log("Response Body", resp.response);
console.log("Response Body", resp.response);
```

Response Body is: -

```
{"client":{"id":452,"name":"Test Attr 1 Value is Hi!!!","client_logo":{"id":543,"path":"https://api.teamapp.myhelpling.com/uploads/client_images/6279486665-1551780183.","thumb":"https://api.teamapp.myhelpling.com/uploads/client_images/thumb_6279486665-1551780183.","medium":"https://api.teamapp.myhelpling.com/uploads/client_images/medium_6279486665-1551780183.","large":"https://api.teamapp.myhelpling.com/uploads/client_images/medium_6279486665-1551780183.","filename":"blob","ratio":1.78}}}
```

but

```
cy.writeFile(
"cypress/fixtures/POST API OUTPUT DATA/Client.json",resp.response
);
```

doesn't save the response body in Client.JSON file.

**cy.writeFile seems to not work in this code. I've verified this by
   passing a JSON e.g. {"A":"B"} and that too didn't make it to the
   JSON.**

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for all you kind help. I've made it work by calling cy.writeFile inside onLoad event before triggering XHR request. Here's the code sample with some other updates that I've made for my other works: -

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  "Post_Bucket",
  (imagePath, imageType, title, img, titleVal) => {
    cy.fixture(imagePath, "binary").then(imageBin => {
      Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob(imageBin, imageType).then(blob => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        const data = new FormData();
        data.set(title, titleVal);
        data.set(img, blob);
        cy.readFile(Cypress.env("IDStore")).then(obj => {
          xhr.open(
            "POST",
            Cypress.env("BucketPostURLPart1") +
              obj.journeyID +
              Cypress.env("BucketPostURLPart2"),
            false
          );
          xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("access-token", accesstoken);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("client", client);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("expiry", expiry);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("token-type", tokentype);
          xhr.setRequestHeader("uid", uid);
          xhr.onload = function() {
            if (this.status === 201) {
              cy.writeFile(
                Cypress.env("BucketOutputFile"),
                JSON.parse(this.responseText)
              );
              cy.readFile(Cypress.env("IDStore")).then(obj => {
                obj.bucketID = JSON.parse(this.responseText).bucket.id;
                cy.writeFile(Cypress.env("IDStore"), obj);
              });
            }
          };
          xhr.send(data);
        });
      });
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the **simple example** try with this one.

```
cy.request('https://jsonplaceholder.cypress.io/users')
.then((response) => {
cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/users.json', response.body)
})
```